# Monitor mobile phone network signal

Tags: android, osx

I do a lot of work on the train, with my mobile phone (Android) projecting a wifi hotspot for me to work on. Since the phone is right beside my laptop, I can always get full signal bars on my wifi, but what I'd like to see somewhere on my laptop is how much *mobile phone signal* my phone is getting, since that's where the connection drops occur.

Must haves:

- Supports Android (on the phone side)
- Supports OSX (on the laptop side)

Ideally also has:

- Support for other mobile and computing platforms
- Shows a connection icon of some sort in the taskbar.